# Residue of $\frac{\cosh^{99} (z/2) \cosh^{2}(z)}{\sinh^{101}(z/2)}$ at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have to calculate $$R:= \operatorname{Res}\left( \frac{\cosh ^{99}\left( z/2\right) \cdot
\cosh ^{2}(z)}{\sinh ^{101}\left( z/2\right) },0\right) .$$

$z_{0}=0$ is a pole of order $101$, so
\begin{eqnarray*}
R &=&\frac{1}{100!}\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{\cosh ^{99}\left(
z/2\right) \cdot \cosh ^{2}(z)}{\sinh ^{101}\left( z/2\right) }z^{101}\right)
^{\left( 100\right) } \\
&=&\frac{2^{101}}{100!}\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\left( \cosh ^{99}\left(
z/2\right)\cdot \cosh ^{2}(z)\cdot\left( \frac{z/2}{\sinh \left( z/2\right) }\right)
^{101}\right) ^{\left( 100\right) }.
\end{eqnarray*}
I don't know how to continue from now on, since one should calculate the $100
$th derivative of the function in parantheses and it seems to be difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to compute the residue of
$$
\coth ^{101} \left( {\frac{z}{2}} \right)\left( {\frac{{\cosh z}}{{\cosh (z/2)}}} \right)^2 
$$
at $z=0$. Note that the residue is
$$
\frac{1}{{2\pi i}}\oint_{(0 + )} {\coth ^{101} \left( {\frac{z}{2}} \right)\left( {\frac{{\cosh z}}{{\cosh (z/2)}}} \right)^2 dz} \mathop  = \limits^{z = 2\tanh ^{ - 1} t} \frac{1}{{\pi i}}\oint_{(0 + )} {\left( {\frac{{t{}^2 + 1}}{{t^2  - 1}}} \right)^2 \frac{{dt}}{{t^{101} }}} .
$$
Here $(0+)$ denotes a positively oriented small loop contour around the origin. Now $$
\left( {\frac{{t{}^2 + 1}}{{t^2  - 1}}} \right)^2  = 1 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {4nt^{2n} } 
$$ for $|t|<1$. Therefore, the residue is
$$
0 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {4n\frac{1}{{\pi i}}\oint_{(0 + )} {\frac{{dt}}{{t^{101 - 2n} }}} }  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {8n\frac{1}{{2\pi i}}\oint_{(0 + )} {\frac{{dt}}{{t^{101 - 2n} }}} }  = 8 \cdot 50 = 400.
$$

Comment: Which contour is $(0+)$? Is it invariant under your substitution?

Comment: It is a small loop contour around the origin with positive orientation. By Cauchy's theorem it can be the same after substitution. I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Excellent solution! Thank you!